# I am adding a font that is a little bit odd to a JLabel and it's not displaying as it should

Tags: java, swing, fonts

So I am working on a small project using Swing and I am trying to add a font to a `JLabel`, the font is a little bit weird it's called [you murderer bb](https://fontmeme.com/fonts/you-murderer-font/), I already am using a font that I added and it works fine, but when I do the exact same thing to this one well... it just displays a regular font.

```
private Font font;
File fontFile = new File("resources\\fonts\\Nunito-Regular.ttf");

try {
    font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontFile);
    font = font.deriveFont(14f);
} catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

private Font titleFont;
fontFile = new File("resources\\fonts\\youmurdererbb_reg.ttf");

try {
    titleFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontFile);
    titleFont = font.deriveFont(40f);
} catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

private JLabel title;
title = new JLabel("Welcom To Eureka");
title.setFont(titleFont);
title.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
title.setForeground(Color.decode("#FFFFFF"));
title.setBounds(228, 125, 354, 50);

private JLabel username;
username = new JLabel("Log In");
username.setFont(font);
username.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
username.setForeground(Color.decode("#BB86FC"));
username.setBounds(682, 80, 48, 20);
username.addMouseListener(new AppControler());
```

so the `username` is working fine and displaying the correct font but the `title` is just displaying a bigger font (i set the size of it to 40) but the font is not the one I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
titleFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontFile);
titleFont = font.deriveFont(40f);
```

Should be:

```
titleFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontFile);
titleFont = titleFont.deriveFont(40f); // <- use the font just created!
```

Result (once 1st word spelling changed):

[image]

Comment: that's soooooo dumb XD

Comment: I did three dumb things today, and if all goes well, I'll do the same tomorrow. ;)